# Capture a boolean as either 1 or 0 from a datagrid checkbox

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I receive my parameters as 1's or 0's to fill a datagrid full of checkboxes. The funny bit here is that the checkbox control recognizes them as booleans! But then my checkbox control has a change property in which these numbers are converted to "true" or "false".

How can I convert this changes to ones and zeroes again to send them back to database?

I believed the ByteArray function "writeAsBoolean" would work, but I forgot the rest of the values inside the datagrid are kept as numbers. So that function will not recognize them and my webservice will ignore them, failing to write the data.

To write them to database I need to loop throughout the datagrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looping through the datagrid anyway, use a ternary expression (where var toDatabase:Number):

toDatabase = (checkBoxVariable.isChecked) ? 1 : 0;

Comment: I loop through the dataprovider that fills my datagrid (sorry I didn't mention that)  which is an arraycollection. This collection ends up as a huge mash up of 1's 0's, true and false's.

Comment: You could get rid of all those Booleans by looping through the dataProvider array collection:

for (var ii:int = 0; ii < dataProvider.length; ++ii)
{
   (dataProvider.getItemAt(ii) == false) ? dataProvider.setItemAt(0, ii) : null;
   (dataProvider.getItemAt(ii) == true) ? dataProvider.setItemAt(1, ii) : null;
}

Comment: For some odd reason I didn't do anything, and it worked, I change the values and it accepts them. Weird.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast them however you like:

```
Boolean(1) //true
Boolean(0) //false
Number(true) //1
Number(false) //0
```

Or what I think you need:

```
String(Number(true)); //"1"
String(Number(false)); //"0"
```